# How do I preload a font before css without access to the head?

Tags: jquery, css, netsuite, preload, suitecommerce

So I'm in a situation where I don't have direct access to the head of my website. I would like to use `<link rel="preload" ...>` to preload some font-awesome fonts that my css is calling via @font-face.

However the first thing that is loaded in the `<head>` of my document is the css.

If I use jquery append (or prepend) later in the document to add my `<link rel="preload" ...>` to the head, before the css, will it work correctly? Meaning will it truly preload the fonts before the stylesheet tries to call them. My thought is that the css will start to load before my jquery is ever read, defeating the purpose of adding my preloaded link to the head.

If there's a better way to do this I'm all ears.

Comment: When your prepend your code, probably the css is fully loaded. Do you have access to the server side?

Comment: Why don't you use Jquery to load the fonts / css on the order you want them to load?

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preload your css/fonts, you must include them via preload tag in your ssp files. Reason, ssp acts as an entry point to SCA system and it gets rendered first prior to executing all your frontend modules.